# Remote debugging fails in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a project that is working fine on my system. I can debug the project without problems. My development system is Win 7 (x64). When I deploy and/or publish this project to my test environment (Windows Server 2003 (x32)), I can no longer debug it. I keep getting an error that states "The following module was built either with optimizations enabled or without debug information." It is referring to one of the DLLs in my project that is from another project in the solution.

This application was originally created in VS 2005. I upgraded it to VS 2010 with no problems. I also felt that the original project needed to be re-factored, so I pulled all of the business and data layer logic and put it into a separate class library project within the solution. The web project also needed to be split up because the same code was running on two different server with different pages on both. However, there was shared presentation logic between the two web projects, so I created another class library project that was specifically for the presentation layer. After all of that, I now have 4 projects (2 class library projects and 2 web projects).

All of the web pages are working correctly, but it appears that I am having some issues with a web service (classic web service, not WCF) in one of the web projects. I am getting erroneous results and I am trying to step through it to find the problem. Please help! I have a pending deadline on this project.

Comment: It might help to know what language(s) you are using.  Also,it's a bit obvious but: you _have_ checked that the DLL in question is being built with debug information and that your deploy/publish process uses the debug version of that DLL?

Comment: Copy the Debug build, not the Release build.

Comment: I am using VB. Yes, everything is in debug mode. In fact, I created a new solution. Then I created new projects for all four (still in debug mode). I setup the projects, and copied in the code. I got the same error message after deployment.

Comment: Something that concerns me is that I am referencing the Oracle.DataAccess dll that is installed in my GAC. When I build my deployment project, that dll gets included in the bin folder. That dll is only referenced in the class library that is mentioned in the debug symbols message. I looked in the project, and it is set for the x86 processor while all of the other referenced dlls (i.e. system, system.data, etc...) have a processor type of MSIL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're building on a 64-bit system and deploying on a 32-bit system. This *may* be your problem.

Also, the account used while setting up remote debugger needs to have admin or power user privileges.

Third, can you debug *any* other assembly remotely? Try building a dummy console app and see if you can debug it remotely.

Also, once you attach a debugger, you can go to Debug > Windows > Modules > select your module and try to load the symbols manually. This may give you additional info as to why its not getting loaded.

Comment: My remote debugging works fine for other apps. I have been working on my Win 7 - 64 bit box for almost a year. I have been publishing and debugging apps on my Win server 2003 - 32 bit test box for years. I have never had an issue with 64-bit vs 32-bit apps.

Comment: I will try your debug -> windows -> modules and get back to you.

Comment: Ok, I was able to connect when I used the modules page to tell where the symbols were. I had to point them to the deployment path on the test server. I have noticed that the Oracle.Access.dll gets separated out when I do my deployment, but not when I do it locally. That is probably causing the problem with debugging, but I still do not know what is causing that.

Comment: Maybe Oracle assembly is GACed? I think if you google you can find out how debugger tries to resolve pdb files (if I remember correctly, it follows the same pattern as dll resolving). Maybe that will shed some light on why it was happening. I'm glad that the manual approach worked for you!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your pretty experienced with remote debugging but I posted three short blogs on my experiences last year that may help you. I was building on a 64 bit Win7 system and deploying to s 32 bit XP. First I had to upgrade my OS from Win 7 Home Ultimate to Pro. Secondly one of posts talks about the problems I had remote debugging the **DEBUG** build! I had to use a **Release** build and set some flags (detailed pic and info in the blog entry).

[Remote Debugging a Release Build](http://syncor.blogspot.com/2010/12/remote-debugging-release-build.html)

[General Remote Debugging advice (and screencast) from VS2008](http://syncor.blogspot.com/2010/09/remote-debugging-in-visual-studio-2008.html)

[Choosing the Right Version of Win 7 for remote debugging](http://syncor.blogspot.com/2010/09/choosing-right-version-of-windows-7-for.html).

Comment: I am running Win 7 Ultimate, so I should be fine with my OS.

Comment: Ok, none of your suggestions helped. Thanks for trying at least.

Comment: It never fails to amuse me the things you can do to get something working in MS world! The saying "Whatever works" cannot be truer in any other world I guess! Your blog posts are enlightening. So you choose release mode but then say output full debug info. Wonder how that assembly looks different from a debug build in ildasm. Maybe I'll try it sometime to see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: @Mrchief my memory on this is already getting fuzzy but I think I eventually traced the problem to the checkmark for "Define DEBUG constant". I never proved it but I think I might have been able to just uncheck that and use a Debug build. That project is coming back to life soon so I'll probably get a chance to revisit this (oh goody).

Comment: @Mrchief I just discovered dependency walker and found out why I can't debug DEBUG builds on the remote computer. I [posted a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794434/remote-debugging-the-debug-build-when-vs-not-installed-on-remote) to see if there is a way to solve this. The question has the details on why DEBUG builds don't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

Go to Project -> Properties -> Build tab

Now make sure "Optimize Code" is unchecked.
Now go to Advanced in the same tab -> In the Debug Info drop down menu check full.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Optimize code is not checked and debug info was set to full.