# Visual C++ .dll missing on different computer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I just started learning C++, and I made a simple program I want to send to my friend so he can see it.

I send him the .exe in release mode, and it STILL gives the "MSVCP110D.dll is missing" error.

I don't know what else to do, I've tried everything.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual C++ executable and missing MSVCR100d.dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406807/visual-c-executable-and-missing-msvcr100d-dll) (also see the second section of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794434/remote-debugging-an-app-with-the-debug-versions-of-the-crt-when-vs-is-not-instal/6794503#6794503) for instructions)

Answer (score 5):

The D in MSVCP110D.dll means you gave him a debug build. Don't do that. Compile your program as Release. If it still doesn't work, he need the Visual C++ Runtime for the correct version of Visual Studio you used to comile.

Answer (score 2):

You can build your program with static MFC library.

SolutionExplorer->Project->mouse right click->Properties->General->Use of MFC = "Use MFC in a Static Library".

Then you can send the .exe to your friend without any dependency problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can link Runtime library statically, so you won't need Redistributable package to be installed.
[image: VS project properties]

(for debug configuration choose "Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)")

Comment: Should I only send the .exe, or do I need other files aswell?

Comment: If you don't link other libraries explicitly, then only .exe will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to link to a static, not a dynamic library. This way your executable will become significantly larger, however it will not require the C++ runtime DLL to be present on his machine at all. See Project → Properties → Configuration Properties → C/C++ → Code Generation → Runtime Library → choose "Multi-threaded (/MT)".