# MSVCP140D.dll & others missing when remote debugging

Tags: visual-studio, dll, remote-debugging

I guess I have a simple problem, but it is somehow not obvious to me:

I have VS 2022 on my build PC, and I have VS 2022 Remote Debugger on my remote target PC.
In my VS project on the build PC, in the debug properties, I configured the remote server and the remote command.
And I use a debug build.

When starting the remote process, I get several message boxes on the remote target PC about missing

- msvcp140d.dll
- ucrtbased.dll
- vcruntime140d.dll

I see the msvcp140.dll (without d) on the remote PC in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 17.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64` (next to the remote debugger exe).

I am able to debug a release build.
But why do I fail with the debug build? Isn't it a usual remote debugging use case?

Comment: You have to deploy the debug DLLs onto the remote machine.  On my machine they are available in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.36.32532\debug_nonredist

Comment: Thanks @Hans! I guess I did not find the already existing answers here on SO, because I searched for msvcp140d.dll. That's also the reason, why I decided to not delete my redundant question. If you would like to provide a separate answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, and as Hans Passant correctly stated in his comment, the needed **debug** dlls need to be copied by hand to the target PC. I used the exe dir as destination.

See also [this learn.microsoft.com article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/preparing-a-test-machine-to-run-a-debug-executable).

Alternatively consider to link against **release** dlls instead: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6794503/16049096).

And here are as a quick-reference the source dirs I used (although there were more instances on the debug PC, I used the files from `debug_nonredist` dirs):

- `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.34.31931\debug_nonredist\x86\Microsoft.VC143.DebugCRT\msvcp140d.dll`
- `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.34.31931\debug_nonredist\x86\Microsoft.VC143.DebugCRT\vcruntime140d.dll`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.UniversalCRT.Debug\10.0.19041.0\Redist\Debug\x86\ucrtbased.dll`